# java, parsing xml with specific symbols

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am trying to get xml from string.
Specific symbols locate in  tags title.
I did it:

```
    public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = "<title> \"sad\" <<dd> ><\n   </title>";
        String pattern = "(<title>)(.+?)([<>'\"&])(.+?)(\n   </title>)";
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(data);          
            while (m.find()) {
                String bugString = m.group(3) + m.group(4);
                String fixed = bugString.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
                fixed = fixed.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
                fixed = fixed.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
                fixed = fixed.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
                fixed = fixed.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
                fixed = fixed.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
                data = data.replace(bugString, fixed);
            }
            System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

But it looks a little ugly. How I can improve it, if I don't want use additional library?

Comment: This is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ However I'd use JAXB to parse XML, it's a standard library now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could influence the String you could put the titles tag text within a CDATA section. Within this you do not have to encode the special XML characters.

CDATA section is explained e.g. here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

So your title could be like

```
 <title> <![CDATA[ here comes my special title with "/<>  ]]> </title>
```